# Why encourage editing and then answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers, badges

I see a set of badges that encourage people to edit someone else's question and then answer it:

- **explainer:** Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
- **refiner:** Edit and answer 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
- **illuminator:** Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

So what is are the most obvious benefits to edit before answering the question (rather than just answer but not edit)?

And will more encouragement of editing questions cause misunderstanding of the original question?

Comment: You can read [all about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/164403) on the Overmeta.

Comment: *"will more encourage of editing on the question cause misunderstand on the origin question?"* - possibly, but if the question was that unclear to begin with then the problem is broader than this badge.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit both *before* and *after* answering the question, up to 12 hours in either direction. On average, editing *improves* understanding of the question.

Editing can include formatting and spelling and grammar improvements; I just did so for your question. Such edits *improve the overall quality*, and that's something we very much want to encourage.

Remember that questions on Stack Overflow are meant to be useful for *future visitors* as well as the person asking the question. Editing helps towards that goal.

Comment: I would add that answerer is generally expected to carefully study the question and understand it well enough, in particular to better figure how it can be improved (compared to regular readers / passers by)